# Beego ORM MySQL: default addr for network '...' unknown

Tags: mysql, go, orm, beego

My database link is a domain name instead of an IP address, and I don't use the ip address. Below is my configuration.

```
orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "mysql", "root:root@*******.aliyuncs.com:3308/dbname?charset=utf8")
```

Error Message：

> register db Ping `default`, default addr for network '***.mysql.rds.aliyuncs.com:3308' unknown
>   must have one register DataBase alias named `default`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I checked on the [go-mysql-driver source code, on file dsn.go:116](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/blob/master/dsn.go#L116), the error only occurs when the network type is `""`.

You might need to specify the selected network type on the connection string (whether it is `tcp` or `unix`). Use the below connection string scheme instead of the one you are using.

```
<username>:<password>@<network-type>(<host>:<port>)/<dbname>
```

With your code, it would be like this:

```
connectionString := "root:root@tcp(*******.aliyuncs.com:3308)/dbname"
orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "mysql", connectionString)
```

Note: network type `tcp` is chosen in the example above.